# altering all column names in table to be lower case in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, multiple-columns, lowercase

let's say I have a table in a postgres db with DDL such as:

```
    CREATE TABLE personnel_data 
    (
    ID serial primary key,
    NAME varchar(50),
    EMAIL_ADDRESS varchar(20),
    last_updated timestamp
    );
```

now i wish to run a query which will alter the table and convert all column names to completely lowercase. my hunch tells me i need to do something like this at the individual column level, but this clearly cumbersome:

```
ALTER TABLE personnel_data
RENAME COLUMN ID to id;
```

my question, then, is how can i create an ALTER statement to change all column names to be lowercase (using lower() ??) in one query?

Thank you!

Comment: If that's the actual DDL for the table, the columns are already lower case.  They would only be saved as upper case if they were quoted.

Answer (score 0):

you have to  create the command dynamically using query below :

```
SELECT 
CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ' ,table_schema,'.', table_name, ' RENAME COLUMN ',column_name,' TO ',LOWER(column_name)), *
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'your_table'
AND table_schema = 'your_schema_name';
```

then execute produced queries

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, though i'm not 100% following (forgive me, i'm an idiot). so let's say my schema is named 'domain', does this look right?

```
select concat('ALTER TABLE ', table_schema,'.', table_name, ' RENAME COLUMN', column_name, ' TO ', lower(column_name)),* 
from domain.columns 
where table_name = 'lower_test'
and table_schema = 'domain';
```

Comment: you are welcome , no , you just need to replace WHERE table_name = 'your_table'
AND table_schema = 'your_schema_name' so for your example it would be `SELECT 
CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ' ,table_schema,'.', table_name, ' RENAME COLUMN ',column_name,' TO ',LOWER(column_name)), *
FROM information_schema.columns  where table_name = 'lower_test' and table_schema = 'domain';`